# Wordpress Custom Fields like functionality

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am trying to create a custom functionality using jQuery whereby I can add two fields dynamically and whatever I input in these fields I later grab as a key-value pair, something akin to WordPress custom fields. Can anybody point me to the right direction
thanks
[image: Something like this]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "on the fly?" If it is just for the session or does not need to be saved on server, suggest you look into

- `window.localStorage` @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage
- `window.sessionStorage` @ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Otherwise you will need some kind of database to store these values, maybe even use Custom Fields if it's on WordPress?